# trying to convert a UTC time to my local time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to convert UTC timestamps to show in my local time as a work week, as shown below:

- Start: 1970-06-08T23:00:00Z -> Tue 09:00
- End 1970-06-11T06:30:00Z -> Sat 17:00

Ultimately, I want it to look like the format below.

Would be awesome Tue-Sat 09:00-17:00

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it yet?

Comment: Did I try using momentJS? yes I have tried it and I keep getting incorrect values.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: This command converts the utc moment('1970-06-08T23:00:00Z').format('MMM. d, YYYY') but I cannot localize it. when I try to use .local() at the end of the previous command, it doesn't run the command

Comment: For example: moment('1970-06-08T23:00:00Z').format('MMM. d, YYYY').local() wont run

Comment: Well, to output to the format you expect, you may need to use something like moment('1970-06-08T23:00:00Z').format('ddd HH:mm'); And for the locale, you can reference here http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/

Comment: Are you really dealing with 1970?  Or is that a placeholder?  You will find time zone rules may have changed since then...